# extracting covid-19 pandemic most recent data per country using a Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to extract some of the most recents data about covid-19 pandemic statistics (number of cases, recoveries, point in time) per country from Wikidata using this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?COVID19_loc ?COVID19_locLabel ?countryLabel ?cases ?timeC ?recoveries ?timeR {  
    ?pandemic wdt:P1269 wd:Q81068910;
    FILTER ( ?pandemic in ( wd:Q83741704)).
    ?pandemic wdt:P527 ?COVID19_loc.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P17 ?country.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P1603 ?cases.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?COVID19_loc wdt:P1603/wdt:P585 ?timeC_Other FILTER ( ?timeC_Other > ?timeC)}.
    ?COVID19_loc wdt:P8010 ?recoveries.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?COVID19_loc wdt:P8010/wdt:P585 ?timeR_Other FILTER ( ?timeR_Other > ?timeR)}.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } }
```

The thing is I'm getting multiples cases and recoveries results instead of the most recents only, also timeC and timeR don't return a thing as shown in the image bellow:
[image]

Comment: what happened to your previous question? I mean, I already provided the answer there - the time is attached to statements, please read about Wikidata data model regarding statement qualifiers. I gave you a sample query which showed how to query for a single country, just try it for all countries - if you get a timeout, think about how to optimize the query or devide it into multiple queries or just download Wikidata into your own triple store

Comment: @UninformedUser your query didn't work and I can't download Wikidata (too voluminous)

Answer (score 0):

WHat about [this one, https://w.wiki/6nqo](https://w.wiki/6nqo) using MAX() functions? It does not use the WIkidata statement qualifiers but it might be a start. Query returns 184 rows, one for each country.

```
SELECT  ?COVID19_loc ?COVID19_locLabel ?countryLabel (MAX(?cases) as ?maxCases)  (MAX(?recoveries) as ?maxRecoveries)  WHERE {
  ?pandemic wdt:P1269 wd:Q81068910.
  FILTER(?pandemic IN(wd:Q83741704))
  ?pandemic wdt:P527 ?COVID19_loc.
  ?COVID19_loc wdt:P17 ?country;
    wdt:P1603 ?cases.
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS {
    ?COVID19_loc (wdt:P1603/wdt:P585) ?timeC_Other.
    FILTER(?timeC_Other > ?timeC)
  })
  ?COVID19_loc wdt:P8010 ?recoveries.
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS {
    ?COVID19_loc (wdt:P8010/wdt:P585) ?timeR_Other.
    FILTER(?timeR_Other > ?timeR)
  })
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?COVID19_loc ?COVID19_locLabel ?countryLabel 
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

Germany and France are not in the ResultList though. So maybe your approach to find countries is incomplete.

Perhaps, instead. search for sovereign states instead Q3624078:  `?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078;`? (TODO)